# What is a good password manager that works well with Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Generally, I'm looking for something that fits the following:
**- offline storing of passwords** (I store my financial and more sensitive stuff in there too, and there is no chance I'm uploading that to Lastpass, no matter how much they say they're "good")
**- preferably in one file** (not in a bunch of files in a bunch of subfolders)
**- must work well with Chrome (autocompletion)** - so far I've been using KeePass but have never been able to get  it to work well (or should I say, at all) with Chrome
**- must be stable** - don't know why, but RoboForm has terrible memory problems (reported it to them, they said they're aware of the problem)

There is a similar question already posted, but the suggestions posted give the appearance like the authors haven't read the question at all.

**Edit: If anyone's managed to talk KeePass into working with the latest Chrome, I'd be equally interested in that too.**

Comment: Doesn't Chrome already have a built in way to store passwords?

Comment: @JamesLitewski: Yes, it does. I avoid it like plague for two reasons. 1. Work on several machines; need an external password file. 2. The two times I backuped my machine with (Chrome backup9 or something like that, it didn't save the passwords from Chrome (interesting enough, it saved the logins). I lost more than 200 passwords on those occations (200 <-- don't ask).

Comment: I was just browing your post and didn't initially notice KeePass and responded, but now deleted. I use KeePass with Chrome, have you configured your global shortcut? I use KeePass across multiple browsers and apps without problems. The one caveat is if you store "Google" passwords, KeePass will offer this on every page since "Google" is in the title of the window. Can you specify what happens when you tried KeePass?

Comment: @WebDesignHero - Hi. Sorry, I didn't catch the first bit about notice/deleted ... but anyways, I tried Keepass with ChromeIPass and KeePassHttp. I tried the last five or six versions of Keepass, and it always gave me some error that the versions are uncompatible. Then I tried (this was some 2 months ago) some tricks recommended on other forums about replacing the dlls, but ... to put long story short ... nothing worked. I just couldn't get it to work with Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

[**LastPass**](http://lastpass.com/) Free allows you to import/export your data, even when you're offline.

Works on all kinds of devices, you can access the password 'vault' online, and has addons for Firefox, **Google Chrome**, Internet Explorer, and works on multiple machines, multiple operating systems (Windows, Mac, & Linux).

[Link for Google Chrome download](https://lastpass.com/misc_download.php?noscroll=1&tab=windows&anchor=cr#windowscr).

It can automatically fill forms, *log you in automatically*, and has a master password login feature, among others...[Comparison chart](https://lastpass.com/features_compare.php) between LastPass Free and Premium.

<sub>I am in no way, shape, or form affiliated with this product.</sub>

Comment: LastPass only saves encrypted data -- all information is encrypted locally before being sent to LastPass's servers and decrypted locally after returning from LastPass's servers. Full analysis discussed on [Security Now](http://twit.tv/sn/256) and [summarized on LastPass's blog](http://blog.lastpass.com/2010/07/lastpass-gets-green-light-from-security.html)